# Unable to remove listeners from another loaded script in mircrosoft edge

Tags: javascript

[image]

In Java script code, when I am trying to mouse drag drop events are not properly working as some other script has event prevent defaults.

I have used following three statements but of no use.

```
var tab= document.getElementById("html");
tab.removeEventListener("drag", B);
$("html").delay(1000).off("drag","B");
$("html").delay(1000).unbind("drag.B");
```

Please find attached the image. How can I remove the following event listeners from it?

`drag->html-> B (thirdparty.js)`

`drag->html-> y (oj3rdpartybundle.js)`

only `cockpitsuto.js` events should work in my current scenario.

Could you please help me out?

Comment: for me it looks like the drag event is not on `#tabBarNav` but rather on `oj-navigationlist-page-level`  it also seems to be `tabbarnav` and not `tabBarNav`.

Comment: no that function is ok to be triggered. But i need to sop drag->html-> B.  So i tried the following also...  

    var tab= document.getElementById("html");  tab.removeEventListener("dragenter");
$("html").delay(1000).off("drag","B");  
$("html").delay(1000).unbind("drag.B");